# webpack split and import modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

New to webpack, code-splitting specifically.

I started out creating a `vendor.js` using the following:

```
    ...
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          vendors: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: 'vendors',
            chunks: 'all',
          },
        },
      },
    },
   ...
```

This was easy to understand, import `main.js` and `vendor.js` in my index.html, worked well, but my `vendor.js` file was still far too big.

I found a tutorial here and it recommended splitting out each package:
`https://medium.com/hackernoon/the-100-correct-way-to-split-your-chunks-with-webpack-f8a9df5b7758`

Which had me split out the modules instead of just creating a big `vendor.js` file
`https://gist.github.com/davidgilbertson/838312f0a948423e4c4da30e29600b16`

```
  ...
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
      minSize: 0,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name(module) {
            // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
            // or node_modules/packageName
            const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

            // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
            return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  ...
```

I did that and it worked well too! I can see all of my bundles in my `/dist/bundles` folder as expected.

**So, what now?**
It seems *REALLY DUMB* to manually list out the `124` packages in my index.html
I'd ideally like to just import them all where needed -- does that mean changing all of my components (I'm cool with doing that, but how?)

---

I have a component that imports the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
```

it looks like these are the relevant files:

```
/dist/bundles/npm.react.myApp.bundle.js
/dist/bundles/npm.material-ui.myApp.bundle.js
```

How can/should I import these in my components?

Comment: Why would you need to change the imports in your source? If those weren't being correctly imported to begin with, Webpack wouldn't be including them in your output.

Comment: I'm not sure where to import the bundles I just created

Comment: Initially all the packages were in `main.js` that worked (but was too large), then I moved them to `vendor.js` that worked too (but was still too large). I then used the config in the tutorial to split out each package into it's own bundle.js (124 now) and I know there's got to be a better way to import them into my app than importing them all one by one in the `index.html`

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you have to import them *anywhere*. The Webpack output is packed for the web, it generally just needs to be *served*.

Comment: Sorry -- yes, I was using the wrong term. How can I / should I *serve*  all 124 packages

Comment: How do you serve the `index.html` file, and why do you think the `.js` files would be handled any differently?

Comment: I use this `<script src="bundles/index.myApp.bundle.js"></script>` in my `index.html`
I'm not sure how to / if it is right to do something like `<script src="bundles/*.myApp.bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: No, thank you. It's unclear if you even *have* a problem, Webpack should be adding the script tags you need to the index file anyway. Maybe check that first.

Comment: Webpack isn't adding any script tags to my index.html

Comment: So I need some solution to ?import?/?serve? the newly created bundles for use by my app

Comment: It looks like I need to use this: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin
Is that what you were  thinking?

Comment: Webpack's `runtime` would friendly help you to find these assets on the `runtime` & `main` chunk loaded. So you don't need to worry about it. Take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `html-webpack-plugin` https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin 
I specified a template with the following body:

```
<body>
  <div id="appRoot"></div>
</body>
```

Which Resulted in the following:

```
<body>
  <div id="appRoot"></div>
  <script ......many..... />
</body>
```

FWIW, I also updated my `output` prop in `webpack.config` with the following:

```
filename: 'main.myApp.[contenthash].bundle.js',
chunkFilename: 'bundles/[name].myApp.bundle.js'
```

I liked adding the `contenthash` to the `main.js` so it'll break caching when I push a new build and I'd have a backup/history in my S3 bucket.